# Is this schematic good?

Tags: relay, pwm, schematics

Here is schematic for DC motor control. Using this I can drive motor in both directions and also send short pulses to motor, to move it only a little bit in desired direction.
Let me explain schematic in detail.

PWM controller is powered using 12V DC (Vin). Modulated signal (Vout) is input signal of first DPDT relay. Depending on which relay is energized, direction of rotation of motor is changed.

D1 and D2 are there because of back EMF protection.
D3 and D4 are there to enable me to drive motor in opposite direction when it goes to limit in one direction.

Using left 4PDT (ON-OFF-ON slide type) I choose whether motor will be powered for long time (as long as one of relays is energized) or for short time (one of relays is energized for short time using pulse signal generated using 555 circuit).
Lets say that we choosed on left 4PDT that voltage which drives motor is "long" (lets call this first ON position of left 4PDT, it is of type ON-OFF-ON).

Using right 4PDT (ON-OFF-ON, momentary) I choose which relay will be energized. Pay attention that in whatever "ON" position is right 4PDT, it will short one part of 555 circuit (one side of C2 with pin 2). You will see soon reason for this :)

When left 4PDT goes in second ON position, then 555 circuit gets power supply (12V DC) and it is ready.
Right 4PDT now has not only function to choose specific relay (thus driving motor in desired direcion), but also to cause process of generation of short pulse using 555 circuit by short connecting one side of C2 with pin 2 (here is where I found this pulse generator http://www.doctronics.co.uk/555.htm#triggering). Generated pulse energize specific relay for short time so motor rotates in specific direction only for short.

Is this ok? :) Is there something what should be changed? I didn't choose values for capacitor and resistor in 555 yet because I still don't know exactly what will be pulse duration. I have normally closed wtiches, DPDT relays and PWM controller.

Motor is linear actuator (http://www.ebay.com/itm/Linear-Actuator-Motor-DC12V-24V-750N-50mm-100mm-200mm-300mm-600mm-For-Electric-/281749055276?var=&hash=item41998d672c:m:mCviYhnG5aL1LRiI4QsowiA), it should arrive in few days.
I should buy other components. Motor amperage is 3A max.

This is PWM controller I have http://www.ebay.com/itm/162002954574?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK:MEBIDX:IT

DPDT relays are http://www.ebay.com/itm/Relay-Omron-LY2NJ-Small-relay-10A-8PIN-Coil-DPDT-12V-DC-/371102969959?hash=item566775f067:g:hmoAAOSwKsRWFmAP .
Which diodes should I use for D1, D2, D3 and D4?

Is this power supply (12V DC) good for this application http://www.ebay.com/itm/AC100-240V-to-DC-12V-2A-3A-5A-6A-8A-10A-Power-Supply-Adapter-Fr-Led-Light-Strip-/331146532722?var=&hash=item4d19df1772:m:mmYVpw9kxcePGAlVHiBpCWQ ?

[image]

Comment: That's a lot of switches & relays ....

Comment: I know :)  But I think this can't be done using smaller number of relays and switches. At least I can't find other solution...

Comment: The first thing you need to realize is that, except for the motor connection, there is no need to switch your ground/-12v connection. Your 555 circuitry and your relay coils can be grounded all the time. This will cut way down on the number of contacts you need, and will increase reliability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified circuit doing the same as your doing.
[image]